# Changing Input Border Colour with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, css

I've read a few questions on SO and I believe I am doing the right thing but it's still not working!

I am using plain old JavaScript as it's legacy code but if I have to I can probably use jQuery too.

I have my form which is of the form(no pun intended):

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateInfoForm()">
    <input type="text" class="boxes" name="Forename" id="Forename" placeholder="Forename" />
    ....
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateInfoForm()
{
    var b=document.forms["myForm"]["Forename"].value;
    var c=document.forms["myForm"]["Surname"].value;
    var f=document.forms["myForm"]["Postcode"].value;
    var g=document.forms["myForm"]["Telno"].value;
    var h=document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;

    if (b==null || b=="")
{
    alert("Enter Forename");
    document.getElementById('Forename').style.borderColor = "#FF0000";

   // before it was using document.forms["myForm"]["Forename"] as the selector but I changed it to try and get it to work. It was also doing .focus() rather than changing the border colour.

    return false;
}
```

Not receiving any errors, I simply get the alert box and then my cursor is placed inside the input, which I also don't want since it's removing the placeholder which is why I have removed the `.focus()` and attempting to change the colour instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's changing the border color, but because the element doesn't have a border it's not applying it try:

```
 document.getElementById('Forename').style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
```

Comment: thanks, tried it but the result is the same. There is already a blue 2px border on all the text input elements so I think it should just change to red but even adding the width doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: hmm thanks for that. I'm now completely confused why my code isn't working :(

Comment: got it in the end, looks like my script was working but then being over written somehow so I just moved it to the bottom of the page and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the border width and style too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after much searching, i have this solution, try it...

```
// Create our shared stylesheet:
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
sheet.replaceSync('#target {color: darkseagreen}');

// Apply the stylesheet to a document:
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
```

It works for me.